# Where can I find resources for best coding practices in web development?

Tags: html, web-development, css, best-practices, server-side-scripting

You'd figure that this would be an easy topic to google, but unfortunately I've been looking for a couple weeks and have yet to find really anything that I'm looking for.

The problems I'm running into, is that the site either **A)** Is about image placement, article placement, eye flow, etc. (general UX) or **B)** Introduction into HTML/CSS/etc.

Neiher A nor B really concerns me. What I'm looking for is the actual low-level coding structure/layout of pages and how they should be properly laid out. I can make a web page look virtually any way I want it to without a problem and I already have a good understanding of UX, I just want to know how to do it based on industry standards on the actual coding/scripting structure.

Yes, I am a beginner and I know that standards like these have been set for many years now. I have not been in the industry for many years and was unable to fit any Web Development classes into my Comp. Sci. coursework in college.

Comment: It might help if you gave an example of what kind of "coding practices" you're talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for the coding spec as opposed to design layout?  The newest working version of HTML, HTML5 is being led by the [WHATWG group](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/).  You might also check out [Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5).  These are the 'bring your propeller hat' websites that you may be looking for.  The WHATWG site describes the spec as it is now and the Mozilla site describes what browsers do and do not support in the current spec (it is a wealth of information for best practice!) as well as how to implement features.

In terms of best design practices, you will get a lot of great ideas for elegant design and future-proofing with [alistapart](http://www.alistapart.com/) and with [CSS Tricks](http://www.css-tricks.com).  These guys are on the bleeding edge of responsive, forward-thinking web design, and they post a lot of articles dealing with browser limitations with newer and future html elements.

Hope these help you.

Comment: good suggestions and dead-on re: propeller hat. Sometimes spec discussions / sheets are a bit dry. Staples regardless in this industry tho - great suggestions

Answer (score 3):

I like alistapart for general articles and neat ideas.

http://www.alistapart.com/

Answer (score 2):

Searching, I found a very large list of useful resources which may interest you:

Use the "Stickies" on this forum:
http://forums.macrumors.com/forumdisplay.php?f=58

Comment: was very skeptical - any domain that espouses a platform (mac in this case) i'm leery of - HOWEVER : http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=171456  Some very useful info for those cutting their teeth (or RE-cutting their teeth in this case) - great suggestion, heres a point :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about security.

Top list of exploits:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page